# How to change the size of the JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, flowlayout

Here is my code. The button is the same size as the `FlowLayout`. How can I make the button smaller?

```
public class javalearning extends JFrame{{

    FlowLayout f = new FlowLayout();
    this.setSize(600,600);

    JFrame j = new JFrame();
    this.setTitle("this is a tittle");

        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Button");
        this.add(button);
        button.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);

        this.setVisible(true);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you forget to `setLayout`, it works fine when I do. Don't use `setBounds` and put it in a `javalearning` constructor and I also suggest you `setDefaultCloseOperation` like

```
public javalearning() {
    FlowLayout f = new FlowLayout();
    this.setLayout(f);
    this.setSize(600, 600);
    this.setTitle("this is a tittle");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText("Button");
    this.add(button);
    // button.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);

    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javalearning m = new javalearning();
}
```

Finally, by convention, Java class names start with a capital letter and are camel case. Something like `JavaLearning` would follow that convention.

Comment: (cough) `setBounds` (cough)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oops. Missed that. Thanks!

Comment: It only confuses the code, but otherwise it's in the right direction ;)

Answer (score 4):

You never set the layout manager (`FlowLayout`) to the frame, therefore the `JFrame` is still using it's default layout manager of `BorderLayout`...

Try using something more like...

```
FlowLayout f = new FlowLayout();
setLayout(f);
this.setTitle("this is a tittle");

JButton button = new JButton();
button.setText("Button");
this.add(button);

this.pack();
this.setVisible(true);
```

instead...

Take a closer look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks. Actually i just reviewed my code and it seems like i forgot to add the setlayout thingy, so now it works fine. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

`FlowLayout` will lay out Components left-to-right (or right-to-left) wrapping them if required. If you wish to explicitly set the size of each `JButton` you should use `setPreferredSize` rather than `setSize` or `setBounds` as layout managers typically make use of the minimum, preferred and maximum sizes when performing a layout.

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setBounds(x, y, height, width);
```

you can give height and width less than 10!
also you can use GridLayout for smaller buttons in one button with for loop